# Java - enum wildcard

Tags: java, enums, wildcard, abstract

I have some problems implementing a Java feature.

I have a list of `Sensors`. I have different kinds of them, they all extend the base class `Sensor`.
I have some abstract functions in the base class, and I want these functions to take an Enum as a parameter. The problem is that the Enum is unique for each sub class, and therefore, I can't declare the Enum in the base class.

The code below has `Enum` as parameter. I know it's not legal syntax, but I just want to illustrate that this is where I want to have the sub class Enum as parameter.

```
private Vector<Sensor> sensors;
```

```
public abstract class Sensor {  
    public Sensor() {}  
    public abstract int getParam(Enum param);  
    public abstract void setParam(Enum param, int value);  
}
```

```
public class TempSensor extends Sensor {
    // Parameter names
    public static enum TEMP_PARAMETERS{ PARAM_ALARM_HI, PARAM_ALARM_LO }

    public TempSensor() {}

    @Override
    public int getParam(TEMP_PARAMETERS param) {
            // Will do some stuff here
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setParam(TEMP_PARAMETERS param, int value) {
            // Will do some stuff here
    }
}
```

If the different Enums implement an interface, I can use the interface as the parameter type in the abstract methods, but then I can pass Enums that don't belong to the respective class as parameter. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want contradictory things. The whole point of using polymorphism is to take advantage of the [substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). 
If you want to have a class hierarchy and be sure the right type is entered to the right object, you may consider using the factory pattern.
I strongly recommend against inheritance on Enums; Java doesn't handle that well.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Assuming you have a marker interface called `MyEnumTypeInterface`, just have your different enums implement that inferface. Then use `MyEnumTypeInterface` as the type of the formal parameter for your methods that accept the enum. However, you need to ensure that you're getting an enum that implements `MyEnumTypeInterface` and not just any other class that implements `MyEnumTypeInterface`:

```
public <E extends Enum<E> & MyEnumTypeInterface>void getParam(E e)
```

This ensures that the formal parameter is an `enum` and that it implements `MyEnumTypeInterface`; the methed won't accept as a parameter, another class that also implements `MyEnumTypeInterface`.

So your classes end up looking like this:

```
public interface MyEnumTypeInterface {
}

public abstract class Sensor {  
    public Sensor() {}  
    public abstract <E extends Enum<E> & MyEnumTypeInterface>int getParam(E param);  
    public abstract <E extends Enum<E> & MyEnumTypeInterface>void setParam(E param, int value);  
}

public enum TempEnum extends MyEnumTypeInterface {
    PARAM_ALARM_HI, 
    PARAM_ALARM_LO
}


public class TempSensor extends Sensor {

    public TempSensor() {}

    @Override
    public<E extends Enum<E> & MyEnumTypeInterface>int getParam(E param) {
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public <E extends Enum<E> & MyEnumTypeInterface>void setParam(E param, int value) {
            // Will do some stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: there's still a problem with different types of Enum that DO extend the basic type. you have no guarantees as for the values defined in it.

Comment: But Enum in Java can not implement interfaces.

Comment: @Vash Subclasses of `Enum` (enums) in Java can implement interfaces.

Comment: @Dan A marker interface is just for type-safety. It doesn't guarantee the values (and it shouldn't). Using a marker-interface for an enum is simply a way to use them at an abstract level (in an abstract class or interface). He shouldn't have to pass in the entire enum object anyway, just the specific value.

Answer (score 0):

So you want each `Sensor` to work a particular param type? That would mean making `Sensor` generic.

```
public abstract class Sensor<P extend Enum<P>> {  
    public Sensor() {}  
    public abstract int getParam(P param);  
    public abstract void setParam(P param, int value);  
}
```

There are probably bigger problems with you design. Fixing those could remove the requirement for the get and set.

Comment: This works to some extent, but the Vector of Sensors complains about parametrization, and I can't parametrize it, because there is not one single Enum to pass to it. The answer is perhaps to have a Vector for each sub class, although it is not ideal?

Comment: @ohm You could use `Vector<Sensor<?>>` (or better `List<Sensor<?>>`). The problem is that the calling code needs to be typesafe. If you had a single `Sensor` object and a single `Param` object, how would you know they are compatible?